# Question regarding the usage of two of G-d's names in Isaiah 55:7

Tags: words, shemos-sacred-names, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Part of Yeshayahu 55:7 says:

> וישוב אל **ה** וירחמהו ואל **אל-הינו** כי ירבה לסלוח

Loose translation -  "He shall to return to *Adonai* and he will be merciful to him and to *Eloheinu*, for he is abundant to forgive."

I understand the 1st part of the excerpt as the name *Adonai* connotes מידת הרחמים - G-d's trait of mercy

But the end of the verse puzzles me. Why does it use *Eloheinu* which is a reference to G-d's מידת הדין - G-d's trait of judgement - as a means of indicating G-d's forgiveness?

Comment: Who said that the first name connotes the trait of mercy? See [Guide for the Perplexed 1:62](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp072.htm).

Comment: @Alex - There's a lot there, and I'm not finding a contradictory idea listed there. If my theory is wrong, why not explain that in your answer?

Comment: I'm not saying your theory is wrong. Just that it might not be universally agreed upon, and therefore if your question is based on such a premise you should support it.

Comment: @Alex I'm unaware that there even is a disagreement - to the point that I wouldn't know where to look for that. My assumption is based on all the teachings I've heard throught many shiurim. Offhand, I think Rash"i on 1st pasuk in Breishit mentions my idea, or alludes to it.